# Накопление в переменную SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

В MySQL есть такая интересная штука, как накопление в переменную. Это когда мы прямо в запросе можем декларировать, инициировать, менять значение и использовать переменную.

```
SELECT @I := @I + Value
FROM Table ORDER BY OrderValue
```

При этом порядок изменений значений переменной соответствует предложению `ORDER BY`, если оно есть. Это иногда очень красиво заменяет отсутствующую в MySQL рекурсию.

В SQL Server такая возможность частично тоже есть. Т.е. мы можем использовать накопление в переменную:

```
SELECT @I += Value
FROM Table
```

Однако, в отличии от MySQL, такие запросы не возвращают датасэт, и использовать эти переменные внутри запроса нельзя(в добавок мы должны декларировать переменные заранее, но это не суть). Т.е. либо инициализируем переменную, либо используем.

Вопрос. Влияет ли сортировка на порядок обновления переменной в SQL Server?

```
--Имеет ли смысл ORDER BY?
SELECT @I += Value
FROM Table
ORDER BY OrderValue
```

Если не имеет, то гарантирует ли уникальный кластерный ключ таблицы `Table` порядок обновлений?

Если тоже нет. То зачем SQL Server оставил возможность накопления в переменную?

Аккумулирую вопросы:

1) влияет ли сортировка на порядок обновления переменной в SQL Server?

2) (если ответ на 1 нет)гарантирует ли уникальный кластерный ключ таблицы `Table` порядок обновлений?

3) (если ответ на 2 нет)зачем SQL Server оставил возможность накопления в переменную?

Comment: У меня += не получается, пишет ошибочный знак=.  
   select top 10  @i = 1+@i  from my_table
работает, но результат можно увидеть после выполнения, т.е. да, порядок имеет значение.

Comment: @nick_n_a, это в MS SQL Server, начиная с версии 2008.

Comment: @pegoopik проверил, order by влияет на содержимое переменной, порядок соблюдается

Comment: @Mike, какая версия сервера? Я как раз сталкивался с тем, что не соблюдает. Потому и задал вопрос.

Comment: @pegoopik  2014 сервер

Comment: @Mike, у меня тоже только 2014, сейчас не получилось сделать кейс, когда это не соблюдается. Оформите всё-таки в виде ответа. Вопрос интересный(для меня по крайней мере)

Comment: @pegoopik 2008 fiddle нормально отработал сортировку. ссылка в ответе.

Comment: @pegoopik Написал на почту ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Sql Server, по-хорошему, если в `select` происходит присвоение значений переменным, то это должно быть присвоение им единственного значения; переменные не должны использоваться для накопления сумм, конкатенации, и вообще какого-либо агрегирования набора строк, поскольку такой способ не является надёжным, не гарантирует стабильного поведения и, как следствие, результата.

**Примеры нестабильного поведения** (проверено на SqlServer версиях 10.50 и 12.0)

Вычисление суммы:

```
declare @sum int = 0

select @sum = @sum + x
from (values (1), (10), (100), (1000)) data(x)
where x between 1 and 100
order by x
--order by 1 - x desc

select @sum
```

В зависимости от выбранной сортировки (`order by x` либо `order by 1 - x desc`), мы будем получать разный результат: `111` либо `100`.

Строковая конкатенация:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = ''

select @str = @str + s
from (values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d')) strdata(s)
where s between 'a' and 'c'
order by s
--order by nullif(s, '')

select @str
```

Аналогично, в зависимости от выбранной сортировки (`order by s` либо `order by nullif(s, '')`), результат получается разный: `abc` либо `c`.

Переменные в `select` являются частным случаем скалярных выражений, которые (по внутренним соображениям query processor-а) могут быть вычислены для каждой строки, а могут - один раз для всего запроса.

Таким образом:

> влияет ли сортировка на порядок обновления переменной в SQL Server?

Да, и, как видим - подчас неожиданно.

> гарантирует ли уникальный кластерный ключ таблицы Table порядок обновлений?

Я бы не стал на это рассчитывать, тем более, что сам подход агрегирования посредством переменной не отличается стабильностью.

> зачем SQL Server оставил возможность накопления в переменную?

Думаю, это просто частный случай более общего синтаксиса `select @a = <expression> ...`, где `<expression>` может быть `<@var> + <column>`, а `<@var>` может быть любой переменной, которая определена ранее, в том числе и `@a`.

Comment: Вот. Хорошие примеры, спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server 2014:

```
create table test(A varchar(10))
insert into test values('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')

declare @I varchar(100) = ''
select @I+=A from test;
select @I

-- Результат: abcd

 declare @I varchar(100) = ''
 select @I+=A from test order by A desc;
 select @I

-- Результат: dcba
```

Так что, как минимум в 2014 сортировка влияет на накопление значения переменной.

[Fiddle MS SQL 2008](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a27f/4/0)

Comment: Чем бы его дополнить, индекс кластерный погонять что ли ? Блин, пытаюсь то же на fiddle с 2008 посмотреть он сейчас не работает

Comment: Могу подтвердить, что на 2008R2 результаты аналогичные. :) В том числе и при наличии кластерного индекса, и при сортировке по дополнительному полю.